# How to include all "vue" files from directory into the build without explicitly importing them

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

is there a way to build all .vue files in my `views/` folder without importing them into my vue application directly?
What I want to achieve is a Router with dynamic route definitions which will be filled from a configuration which is a json filled with name, router path and the component name which should be lazy loaded.
My issue right now: The application does only build the files which are imported somewhere in my application. What I need: Build **all** files in `views/` as chunk in order to be able to have a dynamic Router definition.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give proper solution without any code provided, but I'll try

With code like this:

```js
// route definition loaded from json
const routeDef = [
  { name: 'about', path: '/about', componentName: 'about' },
  { name: 'profile', path: '/profile', componentName: 'profile' }
]

// we can create routes like this
const routes = routeDef.map(function(def) {
  return {
    name: def.name,
    path: def.path,
    component: () => import('@/views/' + def.componentName + '.vue')
  }
})

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: routes
})
```

By using `import('@/views/' + def.componentName + '.vue')` you are telling Webpack *I want to import one of the `.vue` files in the `views` directory but which one will be known at runtime*. So Webpack will bundle all file in that directory and make it available for import at runtime....

Note that what you pass into `import()` is really important - part of the argument must always be a static string so Webpack have at least some clue about the directory (`import(def.componentName)` wont work) - see the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import)

Additional example - loading route definitions from server at runtime

`router.js`

```js
export default createRouter() {
  return axios.get('/getRouteDefinitions').then(function(data) {
    
    const routes = data.routeDef.map(function(def) {
      return {
        name: def.name,
        path: def.path,
        component: () => import('@/views/' + def.componentName + '.vue')
      }
    })

    return new VueRouter({
      routes: routes
    })
  })
}
```

`main.js`

```js
import VueRouter from `VueRouter`
import createRouter from `router.js`

Vue.use(VueRouter)

createRouter().then(function(router) {
  const app = new Vue({
    router
  })
  app.$mount("#app")
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I have to define the list before building the frontend? There is no way to say "okay package X is building some views seperatly and package Y is getting some async route definitions with the named views from package X"

Comment: *So I have to define the list before building the frontend* What list? You mean list of routes (`reouteDef` in my example) ? No, you dont - that list can be loaded asynchronously from the server at runtime. But of course code will look a bit different because you need to create Router after the data are loaded...

Comment: Okay thanks. The way with import to lazy load the vie of a route  is something I knew already. But do you know how I can tell webpack via vue.config.js to compile all file in /views? Because on build the application doesn't know anthing about the routes because they are loading while executing the webpage so it doesn't compile my `views/*.vue` files at all. So the application can't find the view defined fore the route in my router.

Comment: Maybe there is some other problem with your own code (that's why its always good to post some code) but the code in my answer is **enough** to make Webpack bundle all `vue` files from `@/views` directory. It doesn't need to know anything about your routes, that one `import()` statement says it all....

Comment: Okay I will try this. The problem is: At the moment I just try and error stuff for my "concept" :D so there is no real code yet. I'm trying stuff, removing it again, starting over ^^ Just have basic `home` and `home2` vue with `hello world` on it and a router so nothing fancy. Basic setup from `vue-cli create` process

Comment: Thanks alot this helped me already for a concept. Marked it as "solution" :)